# Please help me rewrite or add right condition to the Vue js code

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Basically, I need to make sure variable **shops** is empty, only, if all the **account** values are empty in the map function below.

```js
if (coll.cellData.name === 'account') {
  individualData = {
    isSearch: true,
    account_name: object.name,
    shops: connectedShops.map(shop => ({
      shop_name: shop.name,
      shop_id: shop.id,
      currency_code: shop.currency.name,
      account: object.accounts.find(acc => acc.shop_id === shop.id) ? ? null,
    })),
  };
}
```

Do not have much practise in JS and do not know how to add a condition. Thank you!

I have this code to run after, but sure you can suggest a better idea

```js
var custom_mapping = true;
for (shop in connectedShops) {
  if (object.accounts.find(acc => acc.shop_id === shop.id) === null)
    custom_mapping = false;
}
if (!custom_mapping)
  individualData.shop = []
```

Comment: you want shops to be an empty array if `object.accounts.find(acc => acc.shop_id === shop.id)` returns `undefined`?

Comment: yes, empty array

Comment: @Jiga I added an answer. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```js
if (coll.cellData.name === 'account') {
  individualData = {
    isSearch: true,
    account_name: object.name,
    shops: connectedShops.flatmap(shop => {
      if(!object.accounts.find(acc => acc.shop_id === shop.id)) return [];
      else return {
        shop_name: shop.name,
        shop_id: shop.id,
        currency_code: shop.currency.name,
        account: object.accounts.find(acc => acc.shop_id === shop.id)
      }
    }),
  };
}
```

if `object.accounts.find(acc => acc.shop_id === shop.id)` return `undefined` meaning it can't find `shop_id` in `object.accounts`, then we return empty array.

Comment: TypeError: quickbooksConnectedShops.flatmap is not a functionfor the chome browser =(

Comment: check if `quickbooksConnectedShops` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this requirement by test if all the `account` values are empty or not with the help of [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const obj = {
    accounts: [{
    shop_id: 1
  }, {
    shop_id: 2
  }, {
    shop_id: 4
  }, {
    shop_id: 5
  }]
};

const connectedShops = [{
    name: 'Shop A',
  id: 1,
  currency: {
    name: 'INR'
  }
}, {
    name: 'Shop B',
  id: 3,
  currency: {
    name: 'USD'
  }
}];

const shops = connectedShops.map(shop => {
    return obj.accounts.some(({ shop_id }) => shop_id === shop.id) ? {
    account: obj.accounts.find(({shop_id}) => shop_id === shop.id)
  } : []
});

console.log(shops);
```